# ReferenceError: document is not defined while simple code works

Tags: javascript, html

I want to reference to my object but I get the error.
When I try to do simple code like console.log("Hello"); it works, but if I use document lib it does not.

Html:
[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8FAg.png)

js:
[java script code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqSWL.png)

following error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xF6Dl.png)

Please Help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), showcasing the code in the question **itself**, rather than simply linking to an image containing it. Being able to copy the code helps us to debug it much faster. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: I’m surprised your JavaScript runs. The script tag referencing the code doesn’t import it. (There’s invalid HTML)

Comment: Hello, why it should not?  I posted just a part of the html.

Comment: Edit: sorry, stupid me, I put the src code after the > not before :( thanks for help anyway.

Comment: Do you run your script with Node.js? You should open html in your browser